# why am I getting this TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument error?

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

I was trying to add `tkinter` graphics to a small part of my code for some reason and want the output(calculated sum) on window.How did I make this code working please help!

my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x600')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("HACKER-simple interest setup")

# define entry variables
n1 = StringVar()
n2 = StringVar()
n3 = StringVar()


def simple_interest(*x):
    global principal, time
    principal = float(principal.get())
    time = float(time.get())
    interest_rate = float(ir.get())

    # simple interest calculating engine
    simple_interest(Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)

    Output = Text(window, width=25, bg="light cyan")
    Output.grid(column=0, row=4)
    Output.place(x=150, y=300)
    Output.insert(END, "Simple_Interest:", simple_interest)


lbl = Label(window, text="Principal:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=45, y=125)

lbl = Label(window, text="Time:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=70, y=150)

lbl = Label(window, text="Interest rate:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=12, y=170)

principal = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n1, width=40)
principal.grid(column=0, row=4)
principal.place(x=130, y=130)

time = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n2, width=40)
time.grid(column=0, row=4)
time.place(x=130, y=150)

ir = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n3, width=40)
ir.grid(column=0, row=4)
ir.place(x=130, y=170)

btn = Button(window, text="Calculate", bg="red", fg="white", command=simple_interest)
btn.grid(column=0, row=5)
btn.place(x=220, y=200)

window.mainloop()
```

getting error:

```
C:\Users\Anmol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe "D:/Downloads/si test.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anmol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Downloads/si test.py", line 22, in simple_interest
    simple_interest(Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)
TypeError: simple_interest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Simple_Interest'
```

Comment: change `simple_interest(Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)` to simple_interest(principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time` at line 22.
And you should use the "if" statement in line 17-19

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('400x600')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("HACKER-simple interest setup")

# define entry variables
n1 = StringVar()
n2 = StringVar()
n3 = StringVar()


def simple_interest(*x):
    global principal, time
    principal = float(principal.get() if not isinstance(principal,float) else principal)
    time = float(time.get()) if not isinstance(time,float) else time
    interest_rate = float(ir.get()) if not isinstance(ir,float) else ir

    # simple interest calculating engine
    Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time

    Output = Text(window, width=25, bg="light cyan")
    Output.grid(column=0, row=4)
    Output.place(x=150, y=300)
    Output.insert(END, "Simple_Interest:\n"+str(Simple_Interest))


lbl = Label(window, text="Principal:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=45, y=125)

lbl = Label(window, text="Time:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=70, y=150)

lbl = Label(window, text="Interest rate:", font=("Aerial Bold Italic", 15))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=4)
lbl.place(x=12, y=170)

principal = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n1, width=40)
principal.grid(column=0, row=4)
principal.place(x=130, y=130)

time = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n2, width=40)
time.grid(column=0, row=4)
time.place(x=130, y=150)

ir = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=n3, width=40)
ir.grid(column=0, row=4)
ir.place(x=130, y=170)

btn = Button(window, text="Calculate", bg="red", fg="white", command=simple_interest)
btn.grid(column=0, row=5)
btn.place(x=220, y=200)

window.mainloop()
```

It was worked!
[image]

Comment: First of all this isn't going to work because the function `simple_interest` you called on this line: `simple_interest(Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)` doesn't exist.

Comment: Second of all changing the function name to `sb` just makes the code less readable/debuggable.

Comment: @ helloworldSB click on the button and you will get an error. `simple_interest` isn't defined

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks.I found my vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

change line 22 `simple_interest(Simple_Interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time)`
to `simple_interest=principal * (interest_rate / 100) * time`

change line 27 `Output.insert(END, "Simple_Interest:", simple_interest)` to `Output.insert(END, "Simple_Interest:" + str(simple_interest))`

How was I able to solve it?

I assigned the simple interest to variable simple interest

and for the output, it was just printing 'simple interest' as a string so I replaced it with out result

Comment: Btw `Output.insert(END, "Simple_Interest:" + str(simple_interest))` would have been better.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks for pointing it out, I will edit.